# Keyword not recognised

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

The exact code works for someone else, but on my computer it doesn't, I have the exact files as that person. 
Here you can see the directory and some of the code[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLgpd.png)

And here you can see the fails [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBAOj.png)

Comment: Clearly, there must be something different between the two computers. Without more information it's impossible for us to do anything but guess.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your question and add - as a text - the source code, the error, and any other relevant information - like the directory structure of the project.

The secend screenshot shows errors that resource files are not found; from the output it *looks like* you are importing them as "Resources/file.robot".
In the same time in the first screenshot it *looks like* the Resources folder is on the same level as your suite's one. So change the imports to be "../Resources/file.robot", to set where the framework should find them.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much, changing "Resources/file.robot" to "../Resources/file.robot" solved the problem

Comment: Glad it did; now Do The Right Thing, and edit the question - not that many people would open external attachments; their content is not indexed by the search engines; if someone has the same problem they wouldn't know - they can't see the actual problem; and, no one would have typed out your code just to try to reproduce it and help you. All of this is behind the idea of Stack Overflow, it's not just a "hey I'm stuck someone tell me what to do" system :)